# How are request response tracked in a application server

Tags: web-services, http, soap, jax-ws, application-server

Look at this scenario in a massive webserver/application server
The user sends multiple requests that get processed async and call an webservice.
How is the request response cycle?
How does the application server know which packet of response goes to which request?

I know this is a very silly question, however i am not able to find any documentation on how this is handled?
How does the application server track the request and the response?

Comment: Hello people, any suggestions will be welcome

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's persisted in the app. I am going  to ask the same question a bit later today.